# DDH to DLIN reduction

Tags: diffie-hellman, hardness-assumptions

I read multiple times that it should be feasible to show a reductions from Decisional Diffie Hellmann. Could you give examples?

Answer (score 4):

Given a DLIN solver $L(u,v,h,u^x,v^y,z)$ that returns true if $z=h^{x+y}$ and false otherwise, and a DDH problem $(g,g^a,g^b,t)$ we generate a random element $r$ and compute $L(g,r,g^a,g^b,1,t)$ where 1 is the group identity. In DLIN terms, we are setting $x=b$ and $y=0$. If our computation returns true we deduce that $t=g^{ab}$ and if it returns false we deduce that it is not.

Comment: Does the answer above change the generator? Because the DDH problem has $g$ as generator, and the DLIN solver has $g^a$ as generator (third entry, in place of $h$).

Comment: Per [Boneh et al](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/groupsigs.pdf) $u$, $v$ and $h$ can all be arbitrary generators . $g^a$ is a generator unless $a=0$ in which DDH is trivial.